# Error with vspace and normalfont

Tags: vertical-spacing

I use TeXShop on Mac. After updating to the newest version (I've been negligent for a bit) I've been having difficulty with `\vspace` and `\normalfont`. In particular, `\normalfont` does nothing after using `\large`, and `\vspace` only skips after the next `\\` command, so I've been needing to use `\vspace{} \text{}\\` to get it to work. I've posted below what I have as a minimal working example. I'm not sure if I have an error here (any help appreciated) or if these changed with the update. In either case, any help/suggestions/advice for how to better use `\vspace` and `\normalfont` would be appreciated.

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,margin=.75in,headheight=0.27in,headsep=.1in]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\noindent \large \textbf{The Tangent Problem}\\
\normalfont
\vspace{3cm}\\
test1
\vspace{4cm}
test2
3
4\\
5\\
6\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: that never worked. Use `\normalsize` to get the normal font size, and use \vspace only between paragraphs (after an empty line), inside paragraphs use `\\[3cm]`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on `\normalsize`. I'm still having the same issue with `\vspace`, I can only get a vertical space after using the `\\` command later on elsewhere, even after an empty line (like the line above `4\\`), which requires something like `\vspace{stuff} \text{} \\\` for me. The command `\\\[3cm]` helps, but I still can't get `\vspace` to work out.

Comment: learn some latex basics. E.g. https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-11

Comment: `\normalfont` selects the document default font but that is the current font so it does nothig. avoid using `\\ `  ad `\vspace`, certaily don't use them at the same place, as here.

Comment: Gotcha, should use `\normalsize` not `\normalfont`, silly mistake. I've tried to avoid using `\\ ` and use only line breaks and `\vspace`, but I found that the compiler (or whatever it is) seems to be ignoring `\vspace` unless I also use `\\ `

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX ain't a word processor.

If you want a title, mark it up with `\section` or another related command. If you want to do things by hand, you can, of course.

```
{\large\bfseries The tangent problem\par}

\vspace{3cm}

text

\vspace{4cm}

text
```

The braces around `\large\bfseries` ensure that the font size and shape commands don't leak, it's quite uncommon to have `\normalfont` or `\normalsize` in the document body. The `\par` ensures that the title uses the correct line spacing.

Using `\\` is a sure sign of bad markup.

Better input:

```
\section*{The tangent problem}

Text

Other text
```

With `\section*` you don't get a number.

---

Let's examine your code

```
\noindent \large \textbf{The Tangent Problem}\\
\normalfont
\vspace{3cm}\\
test1
\vspace{4cm}
test2
3
4\\
5\\
6\\
```

The `\large` selection applies to everything, because it's not issued in a group and `\normalfont` does not act on the font size.

The part

```
\normalfont\vspace{3cm}\\
```

is an empty line containing only a `\vspace` instruction, which causes TeX to insert the vertical space after that line and to issue an `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` message (because the line is empty).

Next we have the equivalent of

```
test1 \vspace{4cm} test2 3 4\\
```

which is a single line, because `\vspace` doesn't force ending a paragraph. The vertical space is added after that line.

Next we have a line containing just 5 and another one containing 6.

Output, as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. That worked when I tried that, but I was confused about what was going wrong with `\vspace`. I looked more and found when I had `{\large\bfseries The tangent problem\par} ..
\vspace{1cm} ..
test1 ..
\vspace{2cm} ..
test2 ..
test3`

that test1 test2 and test3 all appeared on the same line still. Could you help me understand this?

Edit: just realized that they all got put on the same line after pressing submit. I have entered  .. everywhere there is a line break.

Comment: @PQ- I added an explanation.